# Can not initialize ESP module in Arduino SoftwareSerial

Tags: arduino-mega, esp8266, wifi, softwareserial

Can not initialize ***ESP module*** in Arduino SoftwareSerial's example sketch in configuring ***WiFi module***.

In the sketch it tells:

```
#include "WiFiEsp.h"
// Emulate Serial1 on pins 6/7 if not present
#ifndef HAVE_HWSERIAL1
#include "SoftwareSerial.h"
SoftwareSerial Serial1(11,12); // RX, TX
#endif
```

I plugged jumper wires in from esp8266 RX to Digital 11 of mega which is RX and TX of esp8266 to Digital 12 of mega, and I compile the code and looked at the Serial Monitor, but it says:

```
[WiFiEsp] Initializing ESP module
[WiFiEsp] >>> TIMEOUT >>>
[WiFiEsp] >>> TIMEOUT >>>
[WiFiEsp] >>> TIMEOUT >>>
[WiFiEsp] >>> TIMEOUT >>>
[WiFiEsp] >>> TIMEOUT >>>
[WiFiEsp] Cannot initialize ESP module
```

Advise is greatly appreciated.

Comment: it is not SoftwareSerial on Mega. Mega has Serial1. did you connect ground? connect Rx to TX and TX to RX. use pins of hardware  Serial1 of Mega

Comment: Yes i connect the ground, my esp01 responds if the connection is RX of esp01 to TX of mega and TX of esp01 to RX of mega.

Answer (score 1):

```cpp
#ifndef HAVE_HWSERIAL1
#include "SoftwareSerial.h"
SoftwareSerial Serial1(11,12); // RX, TX
#endif
```

Because your Mega has a Hardware `Serial1` port, `HAVE_HWSERIAL1` is defined. Thus the lines inside that preprocessor conditional will not be compiled. This means you should connect the ESP8266 to the `Serial1` lines on your Mega:

```
Mega | ESP8266
--------------
19   | TX
18   | RX
```

Comment: I try to plug it in mega's 18 with esp01's TX and 19 with esp01's RX  and reverse but still gives me time out :( i don't know what to do now.

Comment: And also it gives me :error compiling for board arduino /genuino mega or mega2560. please sir help.

Comment: first of all the sketch with WiFiEsp library must compile. what are the error details?

Comment: I download the library in this link:https://github.com/bportaluri/WiFiEsp and tried the ConnectWPA example.

Comment: Then i connect the RX of esp01 to TX 19 of mega and TX of esp01 to RX of mega but still no success.

Comment: and the compile error? changing connections is for nothing if the code doesn't compile and upload